# How to read nodes that have map values only in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm listening to a node that has children with different value types, like in te picture below

[image]

How can I get the values of the nodes that contained map values indicated with red rectangle only ?

I tried to use java class containing the fields in the red rectangle, and an error shows and says "Cannot convert type String to MyObject". So I think its reading the children that have string value first!

Comment: By red rectangle, do you mean all fields under the green rectangle node other than accepted, time, totalPrice, userEmail and userName? And it would be nice if you posted actual JSON rather than a picture. Just use the export JSON option in the console

Comment: Yes, i just want to get what in the red rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should restructure your data to have a separate node just for the data you want to receive.

Comment: Its not safe to do that, since push id doesnt start with dash forever

Comment: Yeah I would use my own key rather than the one firebase gives us for this. Or better yet, a different node for this data that you want to get. Maybe I'll edit the answer. I'm also have a feeling they made sure it starts with dash forever.

Comment: There is an article says that push id doesnt always start with dash

Comment: And now I'll remove it from the answer.. could you provide the link to this article?